# Is the end of a cigarette on fire when lit?

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetics, materials, combustion

Is the end of a cigarette on fire when it is lit? Or is it smoldering? Is there a chemical difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lighted cigarette is burning, technically smoldering (no flame).  The stuff inside the paper bears only a passing resemblance to tobacco,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cigarette#Construction